# ActionScript square drawing

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to draw a square on the stage. I have included this block of code

```
public class Main extends MovieClip 
    {

        public function Main() 
        {
            if (stage) {
                init();
                var mySquare:Square = new Square();
                mySquare.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
                mySquare.graphics.drawRect(200, 200, 60, 60);
                addChild(mySquare);
            }
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point
        }
}
```

But i have 2 squares on the stage. why? how can i change the code?
thank you

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you use a code template that contains this comment :

```
// entry point
```

But you put your code elsewhere. All this code:

```
var mySquare:Square = new Square();
mySquare.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
mySquare.graphics.drawRect(200, 200, 60, 60);
addChild(mySquare);
```

Should be where the comment is and not where it currently is.

> But i have 2 squares on the stage. why?

You add an instance of the class `Square` to the display list. Whatever that object contains will be displayed. Given that you named it the way you did, it probably contains a square.

Additionally, you draw a Square with the drawing API. This would be your second square.